# Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, youtube-data-api

i have trouble getting started with the Android Youtube API.
I have an `ActionBarActivity` that has an `v4.ViewPager` and i wanted to put multiple `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` inside.
I get `Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView`, my tip is that something in the inheritance chain is wrong, but i don't know what.

My code so far:
XML:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="5dp" /> </FrameLayout>
```

Java:

```
public class MyYoutubeFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

private static final String API_KEY = "";

private String videoId = "qNggvk8QtaY";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube, container, false);

    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) view.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(videoId);
    }
}
```

}

LogCat:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at app.com.example.martinhatzung.movieapp.fragments.MyYoutubeFragment.onCreateView(MyYoutubeFragment.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:337)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5786)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Nat
```

Comment: Please put complete logcat trace

Comment: if you find a solution maybe you can post it

Answer (score 0):

Change your class like this. Also don't forget to use real API_KEY, in your code its just an empty string

```
public class MyYoutubeFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {
private static final String API_KEY = "";
private String videoId = "qNggvk8QtaY";

public static MyYoutubeFragment newInstance()
{
    MyYoutubeFragment playerYouTubeFrag = new MyYoutubeFragment();

    playerYouTubeFrag.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    return playerYouTubeFrag;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(videoId);
    }
}
}
```

Also load this as below

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.video_view, MyYoutubeFragment.newInstance())
            .commit();
```

Comment: where do I do the transaction?

Comment: That depends where do you want to load the youtube fragment. for example for original question it should be in the page change event listener.